# Concatenating string and bytes in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to concatenate string and bytes in Python. This isn't working, but I think it could work if we could get rid of the `b''` and treat the bytes object as a string:

```
import binascii

s = 'hello world'

hex_code = binascii.hexlify(bytes(s, 'utf-8'))
print(hex_code) # b'68656c6c6f20776f726c64'

# this would work
print('68656c6c6f20776f726c64' + ' some other string')

# this fails
print(hex_code + ' some other string')
```

My ultimate use case is for something totally unrelated. SQL Server supports [setting metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/context-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) by issuing a `SET CONTEXT_INFO' command which requires the metadata be encoded. Ideally I want to construct this metadata from my application. My command might look something like:

```
import bin2ascii

def set_context(conn, context_info: str):
    hex_string = binascii.hexlify(bytes(context_info, 'utf-8'))
    conn.execute('SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x' + hex_string)
```

This of course isn't working because I can't figure a way to concatenate string and bytes.

Comment: You cannot concatenate strings and bytes. Convert one to the other and then concatenate. As you already thought of: " treat the bytes object as a string" So, your question amounts to "how to convert a bytes object into a string object", So here you can just use `hex_code.decode()` to get back a string... note, you should have used `s.encode('utf-8')` instead of the bytes constructor, just to do it more idiomatically

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga -- ultimately my use case requires a bytes string. How can I get this?

Comment: do you mean to pass to `conn.execute`? Then the simplest way would just be to use a bytes literal there: `conn.execute(b'SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x' + hex_string)` of course, `hex_string` in this case is not a string... it's a bytes object, so that's a misleading name. I would just do `hexlified = binascii.hexlify(context_info.encode('utf-8')); conn.execute(b'SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x' + hexlified)`

Comment: As an aside, it is generally considered a security risk to use naive string concatenation in this case, because it makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. That may or may not be an issue

Comment: SQLI isn't a concern here because the metadata is constructed internally and not from user data. Unfortunately `conn.execute(b'...')` doesn't work with the library I'm using (sqlalchemy).

Comment: OK. What do you mean `conn.execute(b'...')` **doesn't work**. What, **exactly** doesn't work? You said it requires `bytes`, so either it *doesn't* require `bytes` or it's not working for an unrelated reason.

Comment: If it's sqlalchemy, then `conn.execute` **doesn't accept bytes** as you said. Instead, it requires a `str` object, or the specialized sqlalchemy objects... in any case, I've given to you the solution already

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what's the solution? The function doesn't accept bytes. How do we turn bytes into a string that the function can accept?

Comment: I already explained that to you. You would use `hex_string.decode()`. So `conn.execute('SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x' + hex_string.decode())`. Note, you implied the exact opposite, btw, when you stated "ultimately my use case requires a bytes string". It requires **a string**. Not bytes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks - I can give you credit if you want to add it as an official answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210040/discussion-between-rookie-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).